# Create a relation between consecutive elements of a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a query in `neo4j` cypher language that creates a relation chain of nodes, sorted by a certain condition.

For example. I have this query:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.some_property = 'something'
WITH n
ORDER BY n.some_other_property
WITH collect(n) as node_list
```

I need to link every element of the `node_list` with the next element of that list.

Example, if `node_list` contains:

`[a, b, c, d, e]`

The result will be:
`CREATE (a)->[:rel]->(b)->[:rel]->(c)->[:rel]->(d)->[:rel]->(e)`

So the final query will be:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.some_property = 'something'
WITH n
ORDER BY n.some_other_property
WITH collect(n) as node_list
CREATE LINKS OF CONSECUTIVE node_list
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! After you have your collection, get a range of indexes with UNWIND:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.some_property = 'something'
WITH n
ORDER BY n.some_other_property
WITH COLLECT(n) as node_list
UNWIND RANGE(1, SIZE(node_list) - 1) AS idx
WITH node_list[idx - 1] AS from, node_list[idx] AS to
CREATE (from)-[:NEXT]->(to);
```